# Import spring context with specific profile

Tags: spring, classpath, maven-3, spring-profiles

In my java-spring-maven web-application I'm using multiple spring contexts (single context for each project).
For the sake of simplicity let's say I have 2 spring contexts: a.xml and b.xml, each belong to a project: project A and project B where A depends upon B.

a.xml is importing b.xml like this:

```
<import resource="classpath*:/b.xml" />
```

So when loading a.xml, b.xml is loaded as well.

Now, I have 2 spring profiles in my system: **test** and **production** that are used by my contexts (loading different property place holders for each profile).

So in a.xml I got:

```
<!-- Production profile -->
<beans profile="production">
    <context:property-placeholder
        location="classpath:props-for-a.properties"
        ignore-unresolvable="true" ignore-resource-not-found="true" />
</beans>

<!-- Test profile -->
<beans profile="test">
    <context:property-placeholder
        location="classpath*:test-props-for-a.properties"
        ignore-unresolvable="true" />
</beans>
```

And the same convention in b.xml (only loading different properties files).
My properties file are under src/main/resources (production files) and src/test/resources (test files).

Now I have this unit test that looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/a.xml" })
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "test")
public class SomeTestClass {

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
    //Some Test
    }
}
```

In this case, a.xml is loaded in "test" profile and as expected the desired files are loaded (test-props-for-a). b.xml is imported by a.xml but now I experience a strange experience, my properties values from the property file loaded from b.xml are not injected.

For example if I have this property in my property file:

```
connection-ip=1.2.3.4
```

and in my class I got:

```
@Value("${connection-ip}")
private String connectionIP;
```

The value of connectionIP will be "${connection-ip}" instead of "1.2.3.4".

Notice that the file location starts with `classpath*`, without the * I get a FileNotFoundException:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [test-props-for-b.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

To be clear, the file test-props-for-b.properties resides under src/test/resources of project B. Why do I get this?

If I run a test that loads b.xml directly (not imported via a.xml) it works just fine, the test properties  in the file test-props-for-b.properties are loaded as expected.

Am I doing something wrong? Could this be a bug? If so, can you suggest a workaround?

**UPDATE**

I removed the star (*) from the path to my properties file (test-props-for-b.properties) and debugged spring code. In class ClassPathResource this method throws the exception:

```
public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
    InputStream is;
    if (this.clazz != null) {
        is = this.clazz.getResourceAsStream(this.path);
    }
    else {
        is = this.classLoader.getResourceAsStream(this.path);
    }
    if (is == null) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException(getDescription() + " cannot be opened because it does not exist");
    }
    return is;
}
```

Here are the variables values:

this.clazz is null.
this.path holds the file name **test-props-for-b.properties**

And this command returns null:

this.classLoader.getResourceAsStream(this.path);

Why is that? I can clearly see the file under src/test/resources of project B.

Answer (score 1):

After investigating the issue this is my conclusion:

The file could easily be loaded if I could use the suitable class-loader, meaning that in order to load a file  from project A, any class-loader of a class from project A could do the trick, same for project B. But when using the property-placeholder of spring the class-loader of ClassPathResource.java is used, and when it tries to load a resource from a different project it fails to do so (a ClassPathResource gets initialized per property-placeholder, hence per project in my case).

I don't really know how to fix it, currently I have implemented an ugly workaround by duplicating my test properties files (added file **test-props-for-b.properties** to src/test/resources folder of project A, this way I have it duplicated in src/test/resource of project B and A as well).

I'm still looking for a cleaner way.

Comment: Pulling my hair for same issue since months now! No clean solution found yet :( Properties files getting replicated for every dependant module is making things a mess.

Comment: Well, I'm not the only one, some comfort :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to define the spring profiles outside instead of @ActiveProfiles(profiles = "test")?

One example is to define it in maven surefire plugin in this way:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <spring.profiles.active>test</spring.profiles.active>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
                <!-- THE REST OF CONFIGURATIONS -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: I'm running my tests as junit tests from eclipse, so I think that doing so should have no effect, will try anyway. BTW, if I check during the test I can see that the active profile is "test", so this is not the issue.